# How to Use OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Endpoint with Spring Authorization Server 1.1.0

Tags: spring-authorization-server

Spring Authorization Server 1.1.0 with the OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Endpoint

Is it possible in Spring Authorization Server version 1.1.0 to use the OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Endpoint?

Is there anyone who knows where a good example can be found.

Thanks

Willy De Keyser

I always get the following error message:

{
"timestamp": "2023-06-02T21:16:24.850+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"path": "/connect/logout"
}

When I activate Logging Level trace I see the following error message:

Logout request failed: [invalid_request] OpenID Connect 1.0 Logout Request Parameter: id_token_hint

What is id_token_hint?

Answer (score 0):

You must send a `POST` request to `http://your-domain/connect/logout` with the following:

- `id_token_hint` (OpenID Connect id_token)
- `client_id`
- `post_logout_redirect_uri` (optional)

Where the client will be redirected after a successful logout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Logout endpoint seems to work, but does nothing.
You can still use the Access Token after logout to access a resource server. The Spring Authorization Server interospect endpoint also indicates that the Access Token is active.

Comment: The logout endpoint only invalidate session and remove authorization object from Authorization Server. JWT is still alive until it expired. There is no way to invalidate JWT. You need to remove the token in the frontend app and leave it to expire in authorization server.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Is it possible to somehow combine the Logout endpoint with the Revoke endpoint?
The Revoke endpoint can disable the Access Token though.

Comment: @WillyDeKeyser the revocation endpoint cannot invalidate a JWT, because the JWT is stateless. If you want to revoke access tokens and have them immediately invalidated at a resource server, you will need to use opaque tokens instead.

Comment: Thanks, is there an example somewhere. Or can you point me in the right direction? I think there are many users who are looking for the right way to log out.

Comment: If you run the [official samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples) (an oauth2 client, resource server and authz server), the logout endpoint is demonstrated in the sample. You only have to configure the client to use OIDC logout and then initiate logout from the client, which the client sample does.

Comment: @Steve Riesenberg - does any of the following versions of authorization server provide to automatically remove the token row from the database after the token expires or after the user logs out successfully and if not can you please give me some guidance?

Comment: @DHonev, SAS does not automatically revoke tokens on logout as this would not make sense to do automatically. As mentioned above, token revocation does not make sense for JWT access tokens, and revoking refresh tokens would not make sense in many situations. I'm wondering in what situations you feel auto-revoking tokens on logout would useful for. If you're using access tokens as session identifiers, you are likely using them in a way they weren't intended. Regarding guidance, please ask a separate question for that and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: @Steve Riesenberg, I meant  SAS to automatically delete the token row from the database after they expire. Unnecessary entries for already expired tokens are still in the database after they expire.

Comment: That's correct. The JDBC implementation(s) only persist because it (again) wouldn't make sense to automatically delete rows in all situations. You would need to provide your own scheduled job to manage your database, as this is not a feature SAS provides. Spring makes scheduling quite easy with the `@Scheduled` annotation, or you can work with your DBA on an approach that makes the most sense.